# Denying Access To Certain Urls

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I would like to block the access to certain URLs in my spring web application. I did some research and came across "headers". I don't know how to use them though. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using spring-security in your app?

Comment: @rhinds i am using spring-security

Answer (score 0):

One of the most simple way to do this, which I can think of instantly, is to have a pre-defined list of blocked urls and check the request URL against this list in the overridden `requiresAuthentication()` method of your implementation of `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`.

```
@Override    
protected boolean requiresAuthentication(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) {
         List<String> blockedUrls = new Arraylist<>();
         list.add("/foo/");
         if(blockedUrls.contains(request.getRequestURI())) {
             // go to blocked error page
         } else {
             // process the request normally
         }
    }
```

Shishir

Answer (score 0):

How is your spring security configured? can you show us the code/xml?

Assuming you have configured spring-security with your webapp then it is easy to restrict URLs (including role based restrictions).

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/restricted/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll" />
    <form-login login-processing-url="/loginProcess" 
                login-page="/" 
                authentication-failure-url="/?loginFailure=true"/>
    <logout logout-url="/static/j_spring_security_logout"/>
</http>
```

The intercept-url elements define URL patterns and whether anyone/everyone can access that pattern.  Spring will match from the top, so the most specific authentication should be at the top of the list. Also, in the above example, as the final entry matches all URLs, this means anything not specified in other URL patterns will be open.

Taken from this article - it also shows how to achieve the same using code config rather than in xml: http://automateddeveloper.blogspot.co.uk/2014/02/spring-4-xml-to-annotation-configuration.html

Comment: i have this set up. I use these URLs in my android application, do i have to do some extra work on the mobile end to access them  given that Spring security is being used to deny their access. How do i go about this. Thanks

Comment: You want some urls to be available from your mobile application only?

Comment: yes i would like some URLs to be available on the mobile application only